# Play sound on story board complete

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I'm trying to achieve this flow when a page is opened in WP7:

play storyboard "blink" ⇒ play sound ⇒ play storyboard "movement"

I added the sound as a MediaElement as you can see in the code. I had to set AutoPlay="False", or the sound would play instantly when page opens.

The problem is, when the blink storyboard ends the sound is never played. I tacked the MediaEnded trigger onto the MediaElement in the belief that it would refer to the sound specified in the MediaElement. But it does nothing. I tried specifying the sound once more within the PlaySoundAction's "Source" property but it still does not play the sound. I'm thinking the "autoplay=false" thing of MediaElement is a culprit, but I can't take it off as described above.

```
            <MediaElement x:Name="mysound" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" Source="/mysound.mp3" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" Volume="1" AutoPlay="False">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MediaEnded">
                        <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource movement}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <eim:StoryboardCompletedTrigger Storyboard="{StaticResource blink}">
                        <eim:PlaySoundAction Volume="1"/>
                    </eim:StoryboardCompletedTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </MediaElement>
```

Comment: I was first thinking of making one big storyboard for everything, but there doesn't seem to exist a way of adding a sound into a storyboard, or is there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mediaEnded handler is never firing as the media is never being played.

Handle the [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event on the "blink" storyboard. Have that play the sound. Then have the mediaEnded handler start the next stroryboard.

You may find this easier to wire up in C# rather than xaml. (You can always change it once you've got it working, if you wish.)

Comment: Thanks, the Completed event in the storyboard fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of issues with MediaElement as well, and hence prefer using the following to fix this issue.

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Play-multiple-sound-files-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

See if it helps.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll probably go back to look at this later as I'm just starting out with WP7/Silverlight.

Comment: I use the code from that page now as well for another task - it works for wav files, any idea how to make it work with mp3 or other format?